# If condition statement in R having length greater than one

Tags: r

I have written a code for golden section search in R. While evaluating the functions f1 and f2, I have only one element in f1 and f2. But while executing f1f2, the warning says:

> if statement length is greater than one.

My code:

```
golden.section.search1 = function(f, lower.bound, upper.bound, tolerance)
{

   golden.ratio = (sqrt(5)-1)/2

   ### Use the golden ratio to set the initial test points
   x1 = upper.bound - golden.ratio*(upper.bound - lower.bound)
   x2 = lower.bound + golden.ratio*(upper.bound - lower.bound)


   ### Evaluate the function at the test points
   f1 = (1/8)*colSums(f(x1))
   print(f1)
   f2 = (1/8)*colSums(f(x2))
   print(f2)

   iteration = 0

   while (abs(upper.bound - lower.bound) > tolerance)
   {
      iteration = iteration + 1

      cat('', '\n')
      cat('Iteration #', iteration, '\n')

      if (f1 < f2)

      {
         cat('f2 > f1', '\n')
         ### Set the new lower bound
         lower.bound = x2
     cat('New Upper Bound =', upper.bound, '\n')
         cat('New Lower Bound =', lower.bound, '\n')
         ### Set the new upper test point
         ### Use the special result of the golden ratio
         x2 = x1
         f2 = f1

         ### Set the new lower test point
         x1 = lower.bound + golden.ratio*(upper.bound - lower.bound)
    cat('New lower Test Point = ', x2, '\n')
         f1 = f(x1)
      } 
      else
      {

          cat('f2 < f1', '\n')

         ### Set the new upper bound
         upper.bound = x1
         cat('New Upper Bound =', upper.bound, '\n')
         cat('New Lower Bound =', lower.bound, '\n')

         ### Set the new upper test point
         x1 = x2
      cat('New Upper Test Point = ', x1, '\n')

         f1 = f2
         ### Set the new upper test point
         x2 = upper.bound - golden.ratio*(upper.bound - lower.bound)
     cat('New Lower Test Point = ', x2, '\n')
         f2 = f(x2)
      }



  }
   ### Use the mid-point of the final interval as the estimate of the optimzer


 minimizer = (lower.bound + upper.bound)/2
   cat('Estimated Minimizer =', minimizer, '\n')


}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. What is the lower bound, upper bound, f, etc. It looks like the problem is f1 and f2 are returning more than one value.

Comment: lower bound=0.6 upper bound=0.999 tolerance= 0.001 and f is given by code below:                                                                       f=function(minimizer)
{ 
  
  actualvalues<-read.table("actualknown.csv",header=F)   forecastedvalues<-read.table("forecastedknown.csv",header=F)
  error<-actualvalues-forecastedvalues
    meanabsoluteerror<-colMeans(abs(error)) return((abs((actualvalues-(forecastedvalues+minimizer*meanabsoluteerror))/actualvalues))

  

}

Comment: You should add this code directly inside the question. Your code is not yet reproducible. Give an example of what is in actualvalues and forecasted values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer for my question. The function evaluation has to be done within the while loop and this error wont occur.